# configure rules in Sonar lint CLI tool

Tags: command-line-interface, sonarlint

I wanted to configure rules in Sonar lint CLI tool,But not finding any way to do it.

Can any one please suggest way to integrate sonarlint CLI with sonarqube server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the
[SonarLint CLI FAQ](http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/) ,

> **How to configure rules?**
>
> > You can't for now. We might implement this feature in upcoming
> >     versions, probably by allowing to "point" SonarLint to a SonarQube
> >     server instance.

and according to [Sonarlint CLI JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLCLI-15) , this new feature for supporting "sonarQube server connection" is expected to release in Version 2.0 on August 12,2016.

So you can wait for this feature release and most probably procedure to connect SonarQube server will be available in Version 2.0 release notes.

It should be similar to the procedure to connect "Sonarlint Eclipse Plugin to SonarQube server"

Hope this helps